# c++ virtual function and thread

Tags: c++, caffe

here is my main.cpp code:

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
using std::string;

#include "caffe_thread_learn.hpp"

class VideoCaptureTest : public InternalThread {
public:
    string video;
    explicit VideoCaptureTest(string v) : video(v) { StartInternalThread(); }
protected:
    virtual void InternalThreadEntry();
};

void VideoCaptureTest::InternalThreadEntry(){
    std::cout << "video child" << std::endl;
}

int main(){

    InternalThread* vt = new VideoCaptureTest("/Users/zj-db0655/Documents/data/528100078_5768b1b1764438418.mp4");
    delete vt;

    return 0;
}
```

caffe_thread.cpp code:

```
#include "caffe_thread_learn.hpp"


InternalThread::~InternalThread() {
    StopInternalThread();
}

bool InternalThread::is_started() const {
    return thread_ && thread_->joinable();
}

bool InternalThread::must_stop() {
    return thread_ && thread_->interruption_requested();
}

void InternalThread::StopInternalThread() {
    if (is_started()) {
        thread_->interrupt();
        try {
            thread_->join();
        } catch (boost::thread_interrupted&) {
        } catch (std::exception& e) {
            std::cout << "Thread exception: " << e.what();
        }
    }
}


void InternalThread::StartInternalThread() {
    thread_.reset(new boost::thread(&InternalThread::entry, this));
}

void InternalThread::entry() {
    InternalThreadEntry();
}
```

caffe_thread.hpp code

```
#ifndef caffe_thread_learn_hpp
#define caffe_thread_learn_hpp

#include <stdio.h>

#include <boost/thread.hpp>
#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>

namespace boost { class thread; }

class InternalThread {
public:
    InternalThread() : thread_() {}
    virtual ~InternalThread();

    /**
     * Caffe's thread local state will be initialized using the current
     * thread values, e.g. device id, solver index etc. The random seed
     * is initialized using caffe_rng_rand.
     */
    void StartInternalThread();

    /** Will not return until the internal thread has exited. */
    void StopInternalThread();

    bool is_started() const;

protected:
    /* Implement this method in your subclass
     with the code you want your thread to run. */
    virtual void InternalThreadEntry() { std::cout << "parent" << std::endl; }
    virtual void fun() {}

    /* Should be tested when running loops to exit when requested. */
    bool must_stop();

private:
    void entry();

    boost::shared_ptr<boost::thread> thread_;
};

#endif /* caffe_thread_learn_hpp */
```

actually, the output is：parant

However, i think output should be：video child. Because when StartInternalThread in VideoCaptureTest is called, it will new a thread with parameter (&InternalThread::entry, this), and I think this pointer to VideoCaptureTest and will call VideoCaptureTest's InternalThreadEntry which output video child. However, it output parent.

Thanks!

Comment: The right tool to solve such problems is your debugger. You should step through your code line-by-line *before* asking on Stack Overflow. For more help, please read [How to debug small programs (by Eric Lippert)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). At a minimum, you should \[edit] your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example that reproduces your problem, along with the observations you made in the debugger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is likely a timing issue between your threads.  You create a new `VideoCaptureTest` object then immediately delete it before the thread created in `StartInternalThread` has a chance to run.  When the destructor is called, the object will be torn down to an `InternalThread` object before the output has been generated.

Either put a sleep between your new/delete in main or wait for the thread to finish before destroying it.

Comment: great thanks! It works!